# Given $N$ magnets in a 1D line with it's position, prove that there will be $N - 1$ equilibrium points and find them.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, contest-math, physics, mathematical-physics

Each magnet experiences a repulsive force.

The force between a magnet and an object = ($G*m1*m2$)/$d^2$

$d$ is the distance between the magnet and the object with mass $m1$ and $m2$.

$G$ is some constant.

Equilibrium occurs when pulling force from magnets in right is equal to those in left.

I have tried binary search to find some points, but I can't prove that there are $n - 1$ equilibrium point.

Comment: There is something very wrong with your problem. The equation for the force is the equation for gravity. For magnets, the force does not depend on mass. Also, it is not clear from your description what's the arrangement of the magnets.

Comment: Can you write out the equation for the force at point $d$? You then want to show that it is 0 at $N-1$ places, so hopefully we have a polynomial of hopefully degree $N-1$.

Comment: @Andrei I believe you could replace magnets with any other object. And the force to consider is only the Gravitational force.

Comment: @CalvinLin It's actually of degree N, I've tried it for 2 objects and It gives 2 position for equilibrium, one between the object and one outside(which is incorrect).

Comment: @Het Can you show your work?